# Google Analytics shows some visits, but not all visits in the Geo Location

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I visited two relatives in two distant cites, each family member in each location logged into my WordPress blog with their computers and spent over 10 minutes navigating through most of the pages of my blog.

The next day, back home, I checked the GA Geo Location report, which was approximately 15 hours later, and neither city showed up in the Geo Location Primary Dimension: City report.

Does it take longer than 24 hours for their visits to show up in GA, or am I doing something wrong?

I am worried that not all visits to my blog are being recorded by GA.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the person was already logged into a Google account which could shield their location. It's also possible that you might need to change the date at which you are viewing the analytics information.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010052?hl=en

Comment: The date range was correct and I watched both people connect to the website. They do not know what GA is, and I did not login to GA from their computers.

Answer (score 0):

Not all visits get assigned to a city.  Depending on where your visits are coming from, a significant percentage may show up as (not set).  I'm not sure what determines whether or not GA can assign a city, but have noticed that some are missing.  Here is an example, showing that 11 out of 160 visits on one day to my account were (not set).

[image: city not set]

The situation is even worse with the "Metro" dimension, as you can see below.

[image]